# How to get support for a Dell Monitor (2408WFP) in the UK?

Tags: display

I have just spent an hour trying to find out how to contact Dell support regarding my 2408WFP monitor. I have trawled the website, followed all of the 'contact us' links, and even phoned the tech support number they provide, but I cannot find a way to proceed without a freaking Service Tag.

**My monitor doesn't have a damn service tag!**

I'm stumped.

So does anyone know how to get support from Dell for a 2408WFP? I find it utterly astonishing that Dell are performed such a profound **FAIL** on this. I have never had a support experience suck so much. **Shame on you Dell.**

Comment: Did you purchase direct from Dell?

Comment: No, I purchased from Scan - http://www.scan.co.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not the only one with [that problem with dell](http://qwan.org/2005/10/06/dell-support-for-the-service-tag-impaired/). So be prepared to spend some time on the phone. By the looks of it the UK warranty support number is: 0844 444 3844 (hopefully it is different to the one that you tried?)